# How to load partial razor page into razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am trying to replace my view components with razor pages but it seems that it's not possible to load a partial razor page because a model is expected to be passed yet it is my understanding that the model for a razor page should be declared in the OnGetAsync method. Here is my code...

**Razor Page**

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model _BackgroundModel

<form method="POST">
    <div>Name: <input asp-for="Description" /></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Razor Page Code-Behind**

```
public class _BackgroundModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IDataClient _dataClient;

    public _BackgroundModel(IDataClient dataClient)
    {
        _dataClient = dataClient;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public BackgroundDataModel Background { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(int id)
    {
        Background = await _dataClient.GetBackground(id);
    }

    public async Task OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _dataClient.PostBackground(Background);
        }
    }

}
```

**Razor View**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="client-background-tab">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("/Pages/Client/_Background.cshtml", new { id = 1 })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Page Load Error**

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32]',
>   but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'WebApp.Pages.Client._BackgroundModel'

In this example (as per MS recommended approach in their docs) the model is set inside the OnGetAsync method which should be run when the page is requested. I have also tried @await Html.RenderPartialAsync("/Pages/Client/_Background.cshtml", new { id = 1 }) but the same error result.

**How can I load the razor page into my existing view?**

Comment: You view model is `_BackgroundModel ` but you are calling the view with an `int` value. Try some thing like `@await Html.PartialAsync("/Pages/Client/_Background.cshtml", new _BackgroundModel ())`.

Comment: @Azim The model should be created within the `OnGetAsync` within the code-behind file not passed by the calling view. The page load requires an int value as defined at the top of the razor page `@page "{id:int}"` and this int value is passed to `OnGetAsync(int id)` when page loads which is why i'm passing an int value from the calling view and not a model.

Comment: if you are passing model to partial view then why you need to pass 'id' to it

Comment: @Saineshwar this is how razor pages work. They essentially have their own controller in the code-behind file and therefore do not need or expect a model to be passed. this is the same concept as view components which are called with `@await Component.InvokeAsync("name")`. i was looking for a way to load a razor page in a similar way but it doesn't seem this is possible as per reply in the comments of MS docs [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed this cannot be achieved and therefore razor pages cannot be used as a replacement for view components.

See the comments of their docs...

[MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio)

> @RickAndMSFT moderator15 hours ago
>   @OjM You can redirect to the page, or you can make the core view >code into a partial and call it from both.
>
> Pages are not a replacement for partials or View Components.